# How to scrape data from website when dropdown list select?

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, htmlunit-driver

Hi I am trying to scrape data from a web site I want to auto select dropdown menu in that website and then capture all data from the table.

I am having a problem because in that website table id is not available there so I am  confused how can I scrape that value.

Here is my code

```
public class Market {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
      WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.getDefault());
        String market="Rura";
        String url="http://www.upmandiparishad.in/CW_Rates_new.asp";
        driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mktcode"))).selectByVisibleText(market);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.id("what to give here"));
        String htmlTableText = findElement.getText();
        System.out.println(htmlTableText);
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

How can I achieve my output

Comment: @Jason Aller  thx for edit  could u help me

Comment: There are five tables on the page. Why not select the tables by tag and process only the one you want?

Comment: how  could u please  write some code for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with asking someone who stops by a question for an answer by name is that they might not be knowledgeable about the some of the parts of your question. That said I'd try the following which should return a collection of the 5 tables on the page.

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("table"));
```

If/When this doesn't work take a look at http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: When you tell someone something isn't working adding enough details is important. Did you try using it in a form similar to: `List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(By.tagName("table"));`?